# How to refer to the values to be declared in build.gradle

Tags: groovy, teamcity, gradle

I'm totally new to this gradle, teamcity and groovy.
  I'm tryign to write a plugin,which will get the value from **svninfo**. If the developer wants to override the value(in build.gradle) they can override something like this.

> ```
> globalVariables{
>         virtualRepo = "virtualRepo"
>         baseName = "baseName"
>         version = "version"
>         group = "group"
> ```
>
> }

Here i provide the extension called globalvariable.

Now, The jars to be produced shd hav the name according to the values from the build.gradle..
How to get the value from build.gradle in the plugin inorder name the jar???

Comment: @Peter Niederwieser suggested source of information should be all you need, but here's my plugin you can use for reference: https://github.com/rodionmoiseev/gradle-plugins/blob/master/idea-scala-plugin/src/main/groovy/org/rodion/gradle/IdeaScalaBasePlugin.groovy

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question. It's the plugin that installs the extension object, and it's the plugin that needs to do something with it.

Note that the plugin has to defer reading information from the extension object because the latter might only get populated *after* the plugin has run. (A plugin runs when `apply plugin:` is called in a build script. `globalVariables {}` might come after that.) There are several techniques for deferring configuration. In your particular case, if I wanted to use the information provided by the extension object to configure a Jar task, I might use `jar.doFirst { ... }` or `gradle.projectsEvaluated { jar. ... }`.

Before you go about writing plugins, make sure to study the [Writing Custom Plugins](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#custom_plugins) chapter in the Gradle user guide. A search on Stack Overflow or on http://forums.gradle.org should turn up more information on techniques for deferring configuration. Another valuable source of information is the Gradle codebase (e.g. the plugins in the code-quality subproject).

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for ur answer.. I hav a plugin which has to use those values to name jar... and build.gradle file have to intialize those variables... How to do it?